# MySQL Query to show shared columns

Tags: mysql

I have a table that saves the IP address every time a UserID logs in.
Both IP and UserID are keys.
It looks like this:

```
IP                UserID
127.0.0.1         100
127.0.0.1         200
111.111.111.111   200
2.3.4.5           300
8.8.8.8           400
111.111.111.111   500
```

In the table you can see that UserID "200" has logged in using two IPs (127.0.0.1 and 111.111.111.111).

I am trying to think of a query that would return UserIDs "100" and "500" because they used the same IP once to login.

When "200" is looked up, the result would be:

```
UserID
100
500
```

What would be an efficient query?

Comment: See https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
select UserID 
from T 
where IP in (
    select IP 
    from T 
    where UserId = '200'
) and UserID != '200'
```

It shows all UserIDs different then `200` for all IPs that match any of the IPs the user `200` used (thats the subquery)